# How to know if sigsetjmp or siglongjmp fail?

Tags: c++, system-calls

These functions' return value don't imply about whether they succeeded or not. is there a way to know anyway?

Comment: The tags are a bit odd - they aren't system calls, and you usually can't use these functions in C++.

Comment: Really curious, what kind of failure do you want to guard against, and how are you using these in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sigsetjmp` can't fail - it just stores the caller's context into the provided buffer.

`siglongjmp` doesn't return, so there is no way to indicate failure via a return value. You must ensure that the buffer is valid before calling it.

In C++, you usually can't use these functions; calling `longjmp` gives undefined behaviour if there are any automatic objects with non-trivial destructors on the call stack between there and the matching call to `setjmp`.